# Python : Best way to draw 3d function with random x and y

Tags: python, mplot3d

I generated a 2d array, in each row, there is a random x, random y and f(x,y).
I chose random `x` and `y` because `f(x, y)` is very long to compute.

I used `Axes3D` from `mpl_toolkits.mplot3d` to draw the result :

```
ax.scatter(tableau[:,0], tableau[:,1], zs=tableau[:,2], c='r', marker='o')
```

The result is not useful. Impossible to understand the shape of f

[image: draw of f with random x and y]

Is there a better way to draw f(x,y)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your goal is to see the shape of your function better you can rotate the axes with matplotlib method `view_init(elev=None, azim=None)`; it sets the elevation and azimuth of the axes angle . For example:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

# Test 3D function
X, Y, Z = axes3d.get_test_data(0.1)
ax.plot_wireframe(X, Y, Z, rstride=5, cstride=5)

ax.view_init(elev, azim)

plt.draw()
```

With elev=30 and azim=45:

[image]

With elev=30 and azim=90:

[image]

With elev=0 and azim=90:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this answer. since the set of (x,y) is not regular the result is not realy better. I'll add the result as an answer to my question

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
  fig = plt.figure()
  ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
  elev=70 
  azim=30
  X, Y, Z = tableau[:,0], tableau[:,1], tableau[:,2]
  ax.plot_wireframe(X, Y, Z, rstride=5, cstride=5)

  ax.view_init(elev, azim)

  plt.draw()
```